# Como receber o valor dos segundos usando o input time do HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Preciso trabalhar com os campos no MySQL em horas, minutos e segundos como em 00:29:13.

No entanto, aparece apenas a hora e os minutos pra mim:

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" name="hora" placeholder="Hora" id="hora">
```

Como eu altero para poder receber do usuário também os segundos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta desta forma.

```
<input type="time" class="form-control" step="1" name="hora" id="hora">
```

**step** define de quanto em quanto anda os segundos por exemplo se eu colocar `step="10"` o segundos andarão de 10 em 10.